# reload textlabel kivy python

Tags: python, label, global-variables, kivy

Hello I want to have a button that changes a value (num) to a random integer.
so that the num variable changes the global value of labeltext. The problem I encounter is that I can not put the textlabel inside the callback function nor can I **reload the num variable**. As I see it the labeltext loads with the value value num = 0, but it doesnt change as I want it to.

Is there a way to define a function which makes labeltext change on **button-press**?

```
num = 0
array=["lorem","fdw","abcd","icecream","onemore","sword"]
labeltext = array[num]

class word(Widget):

    def callback(self, btn_instance):
        global num
        num = randint(0,5)
        return num

textlabel =Label(text=labeltext,font_size=10)


btnr = Button(text='change the textlabel',pos=(0, 100))


class wordApp(App):

    def build(self):

        gc = word()
        gc.add_widget(btnr)
        global gc
        btnr.bind(on_press=gc.callback)
        gc.add_widget(textlabel)
        return gc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance I hope this helps others too who have the same prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *labeltext* is updated at the top/beginning, you will need to update it again after each new random integer is generated.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from random import randint

num = 0
array = ["lorem", "fdw", "abcd", "icecream", "onemore", "sword"]
labeltext = array[num]


class word(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(word, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.textlabel = Label(text=labeltext, font_size=10)
        btnr = Button(text='change the textlabel', pos=(0, 100))
        btnr.bind(on_press=self.callback)

        self.add_widget(btnr)
        self.add_widget(self.textlabel)

    def callback(self, btn_instance):
        global num
        global labeltext
        print("\tnum={0}, labetext={1}".format(num, labeltext))
        num = randint(0, 5)
        labeltext = array[num]
        print("\tnum={0}, labetext={1}".format(num, labeltext))
        self.textlabel.text = labeltext


class wordApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return word()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - New labeltext]